# Check Liferay Version from Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay, liferay-6

Is there a way to find out which version of Liferay is deployed on the Server from the Browser through Javascript/jQuery or the Source Code?

I have looked at Liferay's Javascript API. It consists of many helpful methods.

[image: Liferay Javascript API]
[image: Liferay Javascript API]
[image: Liferay Javascript API]

Is there a method in the API that I can use to find out which Liferay Version the loaded page is running on?

Edit:
Or is there any other way like checking a loaded resource (js/images/css/source/theme) name from the client-end to confirm that the portal runs on a specific liferay version? Any crude suggestions are welcome.

Comment: and why would you need this? except from google'ing security exploits?

Comment: @MatthiasG: I was just wondering if Liferay provided an API for such thing.

Comment: there is not, i just thought if youd tell me what you want to use it for maybe i could help you out with an alternative

Comment: @MatthiasG - No specific purpose. Just thinking out loud if it was possible to reverse engineer a liferay version from the browser. I've edited the question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple crude suggestions:

1. you could check the server administration page in the control panel.
2. digging into the source for that page, I found that the static Java class `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ReleaseInfo` has all the information regarding the liferay version.

To my knowledge, this information is not readily accessible on publicly available client side, but you can make it so, for instance by inserting the following in your JSP :

```
  <aui:script>
      Liferay.version = "<%=HtmlUtil.escapeJS(com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ReleaseInfo.getReleaseInfo()) %>"
  </aui:script>
```

**EDIT:** 
Liferay does include the build number in its static resource urls as the parameter b. for instance, in the following extract from the liferay.com home page :

```
<link href="[...]/main.css?[...]b=6120&amp;t=1382040996000" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the parameter b=6120 gives the build number of the portal. It is set in PortalImpl.java:

```
@Override
public String getStaticResourceURL(
    HttpServletRequest request, String uri, String queryString,
    long timestamp) {

      [...]

    // Build number

    sb.append("&b=");
    sb.append(ReleaseInfo.getBuildNumber());

      [...]
```

Hope this helps,

Alain

Comment: Hey Alan, Appreciate your help. I need to know the liferay version from the browser. This is for a user who doesn't have access to the control panel. I know it can be done from the server-end code easily. 
Maybe you know anyways of going through the generated HTML code of the portal in the client-end, specific differences that can be observed in the js locations or naming conventions of resource files for each version?

Comment: Felix, I found a reference to the build numbers in the static resource include. See my edits above.

Answer (score 4):

Inspecting the Response Headers with a modern browser you may see a header like:

*Liferay-Portal : Liferay DXP Digital Enterprise…/ Build 7010 / June 15, 2016)*

Hope its useful

Comment: An additional note in respect to this; for security reasons, one can decide not to include this header in the response at all. The behavior for this is customized in Liferay 7 via the portal property `http.header.version.verbosity`. Check out the `portal.properties` file of each version for more information. For instance:  https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.4.3.76-ga76/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L6693-L6711